# Setting the permission for editing block content with a specific role

Tags: 6, users, blocks

I have installed the modules below, but still can not set the permission for editing a block **body** with an specific role. Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks

[Block Access](http://drupal.org/project/block_access)

[Block Content Per Role](http://drupal.org/project/block_cpr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those modules look more like they are meant to simply display different blocks/content depending on user role.  You may be better off utilising [Nodes In Block](http://drupal.org/project/nodesinblock).   Create a content type, or use one of your existing content types and create a node that has the required block content.  Lastly, allow certain roles permissions to edit that particular node.  That will in turn update the block content!